# How does COUNT(DISTINCT) work in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, distinct

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE foo( c1 integer, c2 text )
```

filled as

```
INSERT INTO foo
SELECT id, md5(random()::text))
FROM generate_series(1, 1000000) id
```

I tried to explore the query:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT c2, COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN c1 < 150 THEN c1 ELSE null END)
FROM foo
GROUP BY c2
```

and got only this:

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=145337.34..165315.50 rows=997816 width=37) (actual time=8684.038..12173.533 rows=999766 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=145337.34..147837.34 rows=1000000 width=37) (actual time=8683.918..10402.606 rows=1000000 loops=1)
        Sort Key: c2
        Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 48816kB
        ->  Seq Scan on foo  (cost=0.00..18334.00 rows=1000000 width=37) (actual time=0.102..168.323 rows=1000000 loops=1)
```

The planner didn't provide any information about how the `DISTINCT` operation is performed. So, I tried this to make the plan more verbose:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT st.c2, COUNT(c1)
FROM (
    SELECT c2, CASE WHEN c1 < 150 THEN c1 ELSE null END c1
    FROM foo
    GROUP BY c2, c1
) st
GROUP BY
st.c2
```

and it gave me a little more information about the query:

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=145337.34..170339.34 rows=200 width=37) (actual time=8583.758..10793.980 rows=999766 loops=1)
  ->  Group  (cost=145337.34..155337.34 rows=1000000 width=37) (actual time=8583.747..10362.651 rows=1000000 loops=1)
        ->  Sort  (cost=145337.34..147837.34 rows=1000000 width=37) (actual time=8583.738..10112.619 rows=1000000 loops=1)
              Sort Key: foo.c2, foo.c1
              Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 48816kB
              ->  Seq Scan on foo  (cost=0.00..18334.00 rows=1000000 width=37) (actual time=0.084..168.937 rows=1000000 loops=1)
```

The relative cost of the `GroupAggregate` are all but the same (differ only in 5 `current_setting('seq_page_cost')` and the actual execution time is almost same too.

***QUESTION:*** How does `PostgreSQL` server perform the `COUNT (DISTINCT)` operation. Can it use index (if any) in order to improve perfomance of it? From what I can see it's something close to the second query I provided, but not exactly that...

Comment: Your best reference will be the source code, though I admit that it's not easy to find a succinct explanation for how `any_aggregate_function(DISTINCT expression)` is handled. `process_ordered_aggregate_single` in `src/backend/executor/nodeAgg.c` could be a useful starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres can do a lousy job with `count(distinct)`.  Often, this works better:

```
SELECT c2, COUNT(c1_new)
FROM (SELECT c2, (CASE WHEN c1 < 150 THEN c1 END) as c1_new
      FROM foo
      GROUP BY c2, (CASE WHEN c1 < 150 THEN c1 END)
     ) f
GROUP BY c2;
```

Postgres will choose better algorithms because there is no `count(distinct)` in the outer query.

You may be interested in [this](https://www.periscope.io/blog/count-distinct-in-mysql-postgres-sql-server-and-oracle.html) blog post on the topic.  This happens to be one area where Oracle and SQL Server do a better job.  (And, I find it ironic that Hive has the same problem but for a somewhat different reason.)

Comment: BTW, as I've read about `DISTINCT` using within aggregates, it's possible to make use of index. Is it true? So, `COUNT(DISTINCT col_name)` may be really useful if we have relatively small amount of `work_mem` and index on the `col_name`

Comment: @St.Antario . . . Postgres only recently introduced index-only scans.  I'm not sure if they apply to `count(distinct)`.

Comment: I didn't mean `Index Only Scan`, I meant to avoid using seq-scan and sorting the values to be disstincted explicitly, but use the sorting provided with the Index.

Answer (score 1):

Your query accesses c2 to group by and c1 to count the distinct values below 150. There is no WHERE clause, so you read the whole table.

There are two cases:

- Either you have a covering index (c2,c1), then the table doesn't have to be accessed; it suffices then to read the index.
- Or you don't, then the table itself must be read and it wouldn't make sense to make it more complicated by going via an index.

The covering index has the advantage of being sorted already. Hence this is the faster option of the two.

So all this has nothing to do with COUNT(DISTINCT) and you don't need to know how the DBMS handles COUNT(DISTINCT) internally.

Comment: While useful, I don't think this answers the question.